# Matlab - Unspecified Fault: SOAP Fault: Procedure 'procedure_name' not present

Tags: php, matlab, soap, wsdl

I have a php soap server (services.php)

```
<?php
require_once 'ETD_N.php';
require_once 'ScenGen.php';
require_once 'SickEvo.php';
require_once 'LogEvo_N.php';
require_once 'LogEvo.php';
require_once 'Damager.php';

$server= new SoapServer("webservice.wsdl", array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));

$server->addFunction(SOAP_FUNCTIONS_ALL); 
$server->setClass('soap');
$server->handle();

?>
```

and the related wsdl file to be queried by the clients. If I call the soap server from a php client or a Java client, all works fine and smooth. If I try to call the server with the matlab methods (matlab.wsdl.createWSDLClient('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/webservices/project/webservice.wsdl' , 'C:\Users\jDoe\matlabTemp\project') , all runs fine until the client tries to read the list of the procedures provided by the server. Infact, when the matlab client tries to read the procedures listed by the server, I get:   `Unspecified Fault: SOAP Fault: Procedure 'procedure_name' not present`.
Any idea to solve the enigma?

Comment: What is the payload? Also, where is the call to `matlab.wsdl.createWSDLClient`? Seems there are a lot of missing thing here.

Comment: Hi Christopher,
the matlab code is this:
`
%% Test
% Connect to wsdl
matlab.wsdl.createWSDLClient('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/webservices/IMPRESS/webservice.wsdl');
IMPRESS=patModelService;

%retrieved methods
methods(IMPRESS)

% LogEvo
num_assets=16;
num_hospital_types=5; 
num_patients=500;
delta_T=2;
resource_ID=ceil((num_assets-1)*rand);
hospital_type=ceil((num_hospital_types-1)*rand);
asset_level_init = ceil(10*rand);

res_logevo=LogEvo(IMPRESS,num_patients,hospital_type,resource_ID,asset_level_init,delta_T)
`
the last line is the one that doesn't work